# Exporting with xslxwriter and adding titles from SQlite tables

Tags: python, sqlite, loops, xlsxwriter

I am needing to either add or grab column names from a DB file using Sqlite and Xslx Writer.

The code I have (Shown Below) is my attempt on putting column names in the workbook manually. I am unable to figure out how to alter the loop to write on the second row to allow the titles to stay. I am hoping someone can help me figure this out or have a better way to pull the titles directly from my DB file.

I've tried adjusting "write_row(i, 0, row)" to "write_row(1,0,row)". Which causes it to write under the titles but it only grabs the last line of data from the db. I'm aware that the loop needs i somewhere in that, but I have no idea where.

```
def export():

    todays_date = "Log "+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M") )+ '.xlsx'

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(todays_date)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    conn = sqlite3.connect("logging.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ML")
    mysel = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ML")



    worksheet.write("A1", 'ID')
    worksheet.write("B1", 'Model')
    worksheet.write("C1", 'Serial')
    worksheet.write("D1", 'Test')
    worksheet.write("E1", 'Before')
    worksheet.write("F1", 'After')
    worksheet.write("G1", 'Duration')
    worksheet.write("H1", 'TimeStamp')


    for i, row in enumerate(mysel):
        worksheet.write_row(i, 0, row)
    workbook.close()
    os.startfile(todays_date)
```

Comment: Change to `enumerate(mysel, 1)`

Comment: That solved it thank you!